# Is there an easy way to remove duplicate fields in a CSV?

Tags: bash, darwin

I have a CSV that has dates and names, I want to sort out duplicate dates, but leave all the names by using bash tools.  Eg:

Input CSV:

```
01/01/1960,"Torvalds, Linus"
01/01/1960,"Gates, Bill"
04/20/1960,"Woz, Steve"
```

Output CSV:

```
01/01/1960,"Torvalds, Linus"
,"Gates, Bill"
04/20/1960,"Woz, Steve"
```

I know I could do this using loops and line numbers, but I'm wondering if there's a better way.  Perhaps using sort or uniq?

Comment: Use `sort` and `awk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sort` and `awk` :

```
sort -t',' -k1 input.csv |awk -F, -v OFS=, '($1 in a) {gsub($1,"") } !($1 in a) {a[$1]=$1}1'
01/01/1960,"Gates, Baleee"
,"Gates, Benny"
,"Gates, Bill"
,"Torvalds, Linus"
04/20/1960,"Wozniac, pitor"
,"Woz, Steve"
```

When the input.csv is as follow:

```
 -->cat input.csv
01/01/1960,"Torvalds, Linus"
01/01/1960,"Gates, Bill"
01/01/1960,"Gates, Benny"
04/20/1960,"Woz, Steve"
01/01/1960,"Gates, Baleee"
04/20/1960,"Wozniac, pitor"
```

Explanation: Here, `FS` is set to comma and for each line first column is stored in an array named `a` if its not already present and if its already present then replace the first column with blank using `gsub` function.  `sort` is used to bring dates in sequence.